# Accessing slider value directly in variable

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have created qt (.ui file) and converted it to python file (.py file) in which I have used Horizontal Slider with object name changed to Slider. Now I want to access the value of slider directly into variable (without making use of any functions) which i want to use further in my rest of function. Can any one tell me how to do this. All suggestions are welcome. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is with the PySide bindings, not PyQt but the underlying framework is identical.

Your Horizontal Slider is a [QSlider](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qslider.html) object which inherits from [QAbstractSlider](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractslider.html)

You can access the value currently in the slider by using the `int QAbstractSlider.value (self)` method.

You can call it in your python script by using

```
x = Slider.value()  # x contains the integer value of the slider
```

this value is bound between `Slider.minimum()` and `Slider.maximum()`